# Ajax HtmlEditorExtender image is not uploading

Tags: html, ajax

In design page,i am loading **HtmlEditorExtender** in ajax popup. There i want to load an image. but the image is not loading completely.
i guess:  **OnImageUploadComplete** is not firing.
what could be the problem? and please suggest me the solution??

```
<ajax:HtmlEditorExtender ID="htmEdtior" DisplaySourceTab="true"  OnImageUploadComplete="htmEdtior_OnUploadComplete"
                                TargetControlID="txtWelcomenotes" runat="server">
                                <Toolbar>
                                    <ajax:Undo />
                                    <ajax:Redo />
                                    <ajax:Bold />
                                    <ajax:Italic />
                                    <ajax:Underline />
                                    <ajax:StrikeThrough />
                                    <ajax:Subscript />
                                    <ajax:Superscript />
                                    <ajax:JustifyLeft />
                                    <ajax:JustifyCenter />
                                    <ajax:JustifyRight />
                                    <ajax:JustifyFull />
                                    <ajax:InsertOrderedList />
                                    <ajax:InsertUnorderedList />
                                    <ajax:CreateLink />
                                    <ajax:UnLink />
                                    <ajax:RemoveFormat />
                                    <ajax:SelectAll />
                                    <ajax:UnSelect />
                                    <ajax:Delete />
                                    <ajax:Cut />
                                    <ajax:Copy />
                                    <ajax:Paste />
                                    <ajax:BackgroundColorSelector />
                                    <ajax:ForeColorSelector />
                                    <ajax:FontNameSelector />
                                    <ajax:FontSizeSelector />
                                    <ajax:Indent />
                                    <ajax:Outdent />
                                    <ajax:InsertHorizontalRule />
                                    <ajax:HorizontalSeparator />
                                    <ajax:InsertImage />
                                </Toolbar>
                            </ajax:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have changed every query string which comes from another page to session..... then it worked..... Problemo solved...